React App deployed on Netlify having issues on proxies
I had hosted api on pythonanywhere site I have added the url to the proxy in vite.config.js. Everything seems to be working when fetching the api locally. But after being deployed on netlify (deployed site), I got error in console saying:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Fetching Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
I have endpoints as /api/jobs?isHome=true, /api/jobs, /api/jobs/2(id). In landing page, post limit is set such that it fetches the api accordinly.
 const apiUrl = isHome ? `/api/jobs?isHome=true`:`/api/jobs?isHome=false`;

I had deployed the build(dist) folder to netlify directly without using git/github. I came accross defining _redirect in netlify, but I am not sure I understand it properly. How do I setup/edit it?
vite.config.js
   ....
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://customjob.pythonanywhere.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },

flask_app.py code in pythonanywhere
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def my_app():
   data_set = [{
                id:1,
                #.....
               },
               {
                id:2,
                #.....
               }]

    @app.route('/jobs', methods=["GET"])
    def get_all_jobs():
        is_home = request.args.get('isHome')
        if is_home == 'true':
            limit = 3
        else:
            limit = None  

        if limit is not None:
            return jsonify(data_set[:limit])
        else:
            return jsonify(data_set)

    @app.route('/jobs/<job_id>', methods=["GET"])
    #codes
    @app.route('/jobs', methods=["POST"])
    #codes
    @app.route('/jobs/<job_id>', methods=["PUT", "PATCH"])
    #codes


@babyaga Vite proxy is available in development mode, in production, it is not used. See this post more context.
